# Cannot find -lcrypto

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, ubuntu-18.04, crypto++

I've installed `libcrypto++-dev` and `crypto1` besides their 32-bit versions ( since I think the program I'm trying to compile needs them). But still I get the following error :

```
 /usr/bin/ld: Cannot find -lcrypto
```

Any suggestions ?

I use ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` help?

Answer (score 1):

The linker would be unable to find something like libcrypto.so.1 based on the combo of default/configured and arg-based set of directories to search.

Most likely your lib resides in a dir outside of the linker's default list.
After identifying the lib install dir, replace /usr/local/lib64 within this example:

```
gcc <list-of-objects> -o xyz -L/usr/local/lib64 -lcrypto
```

Comment: But in the output of " pkg-config libcrypto --cflags --libs " there's not any " -L " argument . I think the problem is not about the library directories.